# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel, model, controller, laravel-blade

In code Controller recieving data from model but failed to show in blade view file.
This is blade view code.

```
@for($id = 0;$id < 59;$id++)
    @foreach($data[$id] as $data)
        {{$data->name}}
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

Here is the controller

```
public function cart(){
        $data = array();
        $data['flashSale'] = Product::flashSale();
        $cartProdId = Session::get('prodId');
        for ($id = 0;$id<sizeof($cartProdId);$id++){
            $data[$id] = Product::getCartProduct($cartProdId[$id]); 
        }
        return view('user.cart')->with('data',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Can you update ` {{ $data->name }}` with ` {{ $data->name ?? 'no-name' }}` and check? Seems like for an iteration of foreach, the data is not present

Comment: no progress sir .

Comment: Data already available . I am already getting data with print_r() in controller but failing in view file.

Comment: try php artisan cache:clear in console

Comment: Ok Man thanks for your trying. I solved it by the way without using foreach.

Answer (score 0):

you are using two loops unnecessarily..you can achieve this by using only one loop if it is for or foreach loop...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by single foreach loop. It will save execution/loading time.

```
@foreach($data  as $key => $value)
    {{$value->name}}
@endforeach
```

Do smart work!! .